# Fazer consulta SQL em 3 tabelas e retornar o valor para outra tabela?

Tags: mysql

Tenho 3 tabelas ( A, B, C ) com a coluna `descricao` (com registros diferentes entre elas).

Quero fazer o `SELECT` das três tabelas e enviar o resultado para outra tabela D.

Seria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
SELECT A.descricao, B.descricao, C.descricao FROM A, B, C JOIN D
```

Comment: enviar o resultado, seria: criar uma view, ou salvar os dados em outra tabela?

Comment: A sua pergunta não está muito clara. Qual a estrutura das tabelas? O que você quer dizer com "enviar o resultado para outra tabela D"?

Comment: Para o que foi perguntado, a resposta é a do @JorgeB. , mas vi nos comentários que você quer uma coisa e perguntou outra. Estou votando para fechar essa aqui, mas se descobrir o que quer, é só fazer uma nova pergunta com a dúvida certa (imagino que já tenha resolvido, faz um ano já).

Answer (score 2):

Para inserir o resultado de um `SELECT` numa outra tabela pode fazer assim:

```
INSERT INTO D (descricaoA, descricaoB, descricaoC)
SELECT A.descricao, B.descricao, C.descricao FROM A,B,C
```

Sendo que a tabela D tem o seguinte formato:

```
| descricaoA | descricaoB | descricaoC |
|------------|------------|------------|
|            |            |            |
```

Comment: Não entendi essa query. Você está inserindo registros na tabela D, eu preciso só recuperar os registros (que ja existem) das tabelas A, B, C e exibir na tabela D... Com essa query ele me retorna valor null!!!

Comment: Exibir na tabela D? Como assim?

Comment: Você numa tabela, ou insere, ou atualiza ou apaga. Não sei o que quer dizer com "exibir".

Comment: "SELECT";

Os valores das tabelas A, B, C já existe...esses valores que estão em cada tabela na coluna 'descricao'  tem que ser exibido em outra tabela  ( D ), ou seja, um SELECT dessas tabela, so que eu nao sei montar a query para isso

Comment: @davidsilva eu não sei o que queres dizer com exibido noutra tabela. Para os registos aparecerem noutra tabela têm de ser inseridos nessa tabela.

Comment: Entendo você meu brother. porém com essa query o valor nao é exibido!

Comment: Essa *query* está certa. Eu não consigo entender é o que é "exibir os valores na tabela D".

Comment: Pode estar certa sim, só que no meu caso não. o 'exibir' é justamente recuperar os dados das tabelas.

Comment: Então queres exibir no PHP, C#, etc? Exibir noutra tabela da base de dados pelo menos eu nunca ouvi falar...

Comment: O SQL apresentado é composto de dois comandos: um select, que obtém os dados das tabelas A, B e C, e um insert, que usa os dados retornados pelo select para preencher linhas da tabela D, pareando as colunas do select com as colunas da tabela D. Feito isso, basta dar select na tabela D para obter os resultados.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma view para isso:

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS view_D;
CREATE VIEW view_D AS
SELECT descricao FROM tab_A
union
SELECT descricao FROM tab_B
union
SELECT descricao FROM tab_C;
```

E depois selecionar os dados desta view:

```
Select * from view_D;
```